# Triggering a rollout after pushing a new image

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I followed the tutorial here https://cloud.google.com/python/django/container-engine#initialize_your_cloud_sql_instance

I have successfully deployed my service but the tutorial stops before getting to updating the deployment.

What I've tried to do is this. But it doesn't seem to actually update the pods or deploy the code.

```
docker build -t gcr.io/<my-app>/polls .
gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/<my-app>/polls
kubectl apply -f polls.yaml
```

Comment: Can you show the polls.yaml content?

Comment: Yeah, the source is here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/container_engine/django_tutorial/polls.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the note and example in the docs about [updating a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment):

> **Note:** A Deployment’s rollout is triggered if and only if the Deployment’s pod template (that is, .spec.template) is changed, for example if the labels or container images of the template are updated.

Even though you have pushed a new image version the template itself is unchanged; the template still refers to the image as `gcr.io/<my-app>/polls` or `gcr.io/<my-app>/polls:latest`. And although the meaning of that is changed the *string itself* is unchanged.

To trigger an update push a new tag, say `gcr.io/<my-app>/polls:v2`, edit the yaml file and execute `kubectl apply -f polls.yaml`.

You can also use `kubectl set image` to trigger an update without changing the Deployment yaml file ([demo](https://asciinema.org/a/132998)); the same rule applies, the string identifying the image must change from what is deployed at the moment.

If you don't want create image tags you can also use the `sha256sum` of your new image (the value is displayed when you push the image); works in the yaml file too:

```
kubectl set image deploy/mydeployment mycontainer=gcr.io/<my-app>/polls@sha256:2aac5e7514fbc77125bd315abe9e7b0257db05fe498af01a58e239ebaccf82a8
```

The discussion about this inconvenience is in [issue #33664](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33664) if you are interested in other ideas.

Comment: So I would adjust the this line in the file to include the tag? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/container_engine/django_tutorial/polls.yaml#L42

Comment: Yep. Like :V2 and kubectl apply

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation. Wondering how deployments handle this. Do they template in the sha256sum or version tag and then deploy off that. Or manually update and save the updated yaml file in version control.

Comment: There is a good [article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/continuous-delivery-kubernetes) about ci/cd options on k8s